# Problem with vertices after updating to 3.0

Tags: modeling, edit-mode, vertices, transforms

Some of the vertices on a model I had made in blender 2.90.1 started going crazy whenever I try to move, scale or rotate them on edit mode right after updating to blender 3.0,

Going back and opening the file on 2.90.1 doesn't solve anything as the issue persists, and I have no idea how I can solve this problem or why its happening in the first place.  The weird thing is that it only affects some of the vertices on the model, not all of them.

[image]

[image]

[image]

There are no vertex groups present and the only modifiers it has is mirror and subdivision, but even removing them both does nothing.

Comment: there must be an issue with a mirror option somewhere, if you don't find, please share your file: https://pasteall.org/blend/

Comment: here is the file https://pasteall.org/blend/c5ebe911d8334c579f787a9b54cdc196

Answer (score 0):

Disable the mesh symmetry on Y:

[image]

Comment: Thanks that did the trick, I still wonder why it makes the vertices go crazy though. Shouldn't symmetry work like a mirror modifier?

Comment: I don't know, I wonder if it's not a bug when you use both this symmetry and a Mirror modifier? Also keep in mind that your object orientation is currently not aligned with the world orientation